# Thymeleaf Spring Chechbox List

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Всем добрый день, имеется вот такая проблема:

Имеется вьюшка, где нужно поставить несколько галочек в ответах, далее эти ответы должны отправляться в Controller и уже обрабатываться. Не нашел прямого ответа как решить эту проблему.

Thymeleaf:

```
<div>
        <table class="table table-hover" th:if="${question.getType() == 'multiple'}">
            <form th:action="@{/quiz/question/answer/multiple}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Variant</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="answer, itrStat : ${answers}">
                    <td th:text="${itrStat.index + 1}"/>
                    <td th:text="${answer.getTitle()}"/>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox"  th:field="*{answerListForMultiplyAnswer[__${answer.getId()}__]}">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
            </form>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Далее у нас контроллер, который отправляет в на эту страницу:

```
@GetMapping("question/answer/{userChoiceQuestion}/{quizId}")
    public String questionAnswer(Model model,
                                 @PathVariable("userChoiceQuestion") Long userChoiceQuestion,
                                 @PathVariable("quizId") Long quizId,
                                 HttpSession session) {
        Question question = questionService.getOneById(userChoiceQuestion);
        List<Answer> answers = answerService.getAllAnswersByQuestionId(question.getId());
        List<Long> answerListForMultiplyAnswer = new ArrayList<>();
        model.addAttribute("answerListForMultiplyAnswer",answerListForMultiplyAnswer);
        model.addAttribute("question",question);
        model.addAttribute("quizId",quizId);
        model.addAttribute("answers",answers);
        return "question_answer";
```

А вот теперь метод, который должен все это дело принять (по факту только список из выбранных answerId):

```
@PostMapping("/question/answer/multiple")
    public void multipleAnswerToQuestion(Model model,
                                           @RequestParam("answerListForMultiplyAnswer") List<Long> multiplyAnswers) {
        System.out.println(multiplyAnswers);
    }
```

Суть вопроса:

1. как правильно засунуть в List answerListForMultiplyAnswer несколько AnswerId через CheckBox?
2. Как правильно отправить этот List в POST запрос.
3. Как правильно принять этот List в Controller?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь в вопросе.

Всем хорошего дня!

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, никто не ответил, но я уже сам разобрался, вдруг кому-то будет полезно.

И так, чтобы принять несколько значений, мы убираем лишнее из Controller, который переводит на страницу с Thymeleaf:

```
    @GetMapping("question/answer/{userChoiceQuestion}/{quizId}")
    public String questionAnswer(Model model,
                                 @PathVariable("userChoiceQuestion") Long userChoiceQuestion,
                                 @PathVariable("quizId") Long quizId,
                                 HttpSession session) {
        Question question = questionService.getOneById(userChoiceQuestion);
        List<Answer> answers = answerService.getAllAnswersByQuestionId(question.getId());
//тут был лишний List<Long> который я создавал, он не нужен (!)
        model.addAttribute("question",question);
        model.addAttribute("quizId",quizId);
        model.addAttribute("answers",answers);
        return "question_answer";
    }
```

Далее в самой вьюшке добавляем всего-лишь вот такую строчку в :

```
<table class="table table-hover" th:if="${question.getType() == 'multiple'}">
            <form th:action="@{/quiz/question/answer/multiple}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Variant</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="answer, itrStat : ${answers}">
                    <td th:text="${itrStat.index + 1}"/>
                    <td th:text="${answer.getTitle()}"/>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="answerList" th:value="${answer.getId()}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="quizId" th:value="${quizId}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="questionId" th:value="${question.getId()}"> <!-- МЕНЯЕМ ТОЛЬКО ВОТ ТУТ-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
            </form>
        </table>
```

А сам контроллер, который будет получать данные будет выглядеть вот так:

```
@PostMapping("/question/answer/multiple")
    public String multipleAnswerToQuestion(Model model,
                                         @RequestParam("answerList") Long[] answerList,
                                         @RequestParam("questionId") Long questionId,
                                         @RequestParam("quizId") Long quizId,
                                         HttpSession httpSession) {
        for (Long answerId : answerList) {
            outcomeMakerService.addToOutcomeMaker(httpSession,answerId,questionId,quizId);
        }
        OutcomeMaker outcomeMaker = outcomeMakerService.getCurrentMaker(httpSession);
        model.addAttribute("outcomeMaker", outcomeMaker);
        model.addAttribute("quizId",quizId);
        return "success_answer";
    }
```

Подведя итог:
Чтобы получить множественные значения нам нужно сделать form с кнопкой отправки POST запроса, в самом input checkbox указать какое имя у нас будет передаваться, далее какое оно должно принимать значение, а со стороны Controller мы просто ловим [] тех данных, которые нам требуются.

Все достаточно легко!

Если помогло - апайте сообщение!

Всем хорошего дня!